# If i change the package name of my app... when i upload to googleplay the users will can update their apps?

Tags: android, publish, google-play

Hi I have an app on googleplay and I updated the code of the app.

I moved the main activity of my app to another package, from com.myapp to com.myapp.activities. So I must change the package name on the manifest to com.myapp.activities.

Now, I want to upload this update of my app to googleplay. Will the package name change give users problems when they update their apps to this newer version?

Answer (score 2):

The `package` attribute of the `manifest` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` cannot change once you've uploaded the app to Google Play. This is the unique ID of the application and cannot be changed one it's published.

However, you *can* move the  main activity itself; just move it to the new package (as you did), then change:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" ... />
```

... to:

```
<activity android:name="com.myapp.activities.MyActivity" ... />
```

Comment: Note that if you do this, any icons related to this activity on your users' homescreens will disappear, and they'll have to readd them. Not a disaster, but still not a change I would make lightly.

Comment: Yeah, it also has implications for wallpapers and appwidgets. This is a pretty good read for published apps: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html